# How to get more than the 16 Analog INs on a Arduino Mega for using like 24 piezo sensors

Tags: arduino-mega, midi, multiplexer

i bought an Arduino Mega2560 and flashed it with usbmidi. So now it comes up as a midi device.

I need more than those 16 analog ins to be able to put all my 24 piezo sensors into it to receive midi signals from it. I still have no idea how i have to put the piezo pieces into the arduino but also no clue as how to get more than those 16 analog slots. Any way to use the digital inputs as well or do i need some extension shield or so? I'm a total beginner with arduino...

Comment: When you are a total beginner, can you start with 16 piezo sensors? You could buy two arduino leonardo boards: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Arduino_BoardLeonardo or use multiplexers: https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11976 or external ADC (as Michel Keijzers wrote in his answer). A digital pin for a piezo sensor is possible, but then you can not tune the level in software, so I prefer analog inputs.

Comment: I already have an Arduino Mega flashed with hiduino (
https://github.com/ddiakopoulos/hiduino) ... :/ 
Also it's for a setup with a lot of bells. A friend is making music (bells and chimes) which i want to connect the piezos to and then send midi signals to me to visualize the sounds^^

Answer (score 1):

You can customize a controllino on their page
https://www.controllino.biz/controllino-myplc/
I just looked at it and it seems you can get 24 analog outputs.

Don't know what the cost is though.

Answer (score 0):

You need one (or more) external ADC (analog digital converters).

For example the [ADS1115](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/assembly-and-wiring), the link shows an Adafruit model and how to use it.

In a DIP format (to be used on breadboards/prototype boards) it will be hard to find a 16 channel ADC, but you can add multiple I2C (or other) 4 channel ADCs to one Arduino Mega.